# Retrofit Response{protocol=h2, code=404, message=, url=https://myurl/api/}

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2, server-response

i am sending the request using retrofit2 but in response i am getting the following error

> Response{protocol=h2, code=404, message=, url=https://myurl/api/}

here i am passing my base url to request

> static final String BASE_URL = "https://myurl/";

here is my controller class.

```
private static Retrofit retrofit;

public static Retrofit getClient() {
    if (retrofit == null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
```

here is my interface.
here i am passing the body with parameters and header using map

```
public interface AddProductApi {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("api/")
    Call<BodyOfAddPro> loadChanges(@FieldMap Map<String,String> body, 
@HeaderMap Map<String, String> header);
}
```

here is my api call function
here i am passing the parameters to get response. and i am getting the error response which i had shown above.

```
private void retroApiCall() {

    addProductApi = Controller.getClient().create(AddProductApi.class);

Map<String, String> addproductParams = new HashMap<String,String>();
addproductParams.put("UserID", sharedpreferences.getString("UserID", 
""));
    addproductParams.put("CategoryID", subsubCategoryID);

   addproductParams.put("ProductPrice",productPrice.getText().toString());
   addproductParams.put("DeliveryTime",Time.getText().toString();
   addproductParams.put("ProductType",itemCondition.getText().toString());
   addproductParams.put("OutOfStock", outofStock);
   addproductParams.put("IsActive", "1");


    Log.e("body",addproductParams.toString());

    Map<String, String> header = new HashMap<>();
    header.put("Verifytoken", sharedpreferences.getString("ApiToken",""));

    Log.e("header", header.toString());

    Call<BodyOfAddPro>call1
    =addProductApi.loadChanges(addproductParams,header);
    call1.enqueue(new Callback<BodyOfAddPro>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<BodyOfAddPro> call, 
retrofit2.Response<BodyOfAddPro> response) {
            BodyOfAddPro loginResponse = response.body();

            Log.e("retroresponse", "Response 1 --> " + response);

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<BodyOfAddPro> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("retroresponseerror", "Response 1 --> " + 
t.getMessage());

   }
    });

}
```

looking for the answer.!

Comment: copy the url you received with the error and try using it with postman, check if you are hitting the intended end point with it.

Comment: its working fine on postman.

Comment: Try to replace your BASE_URL with https://myurl (without ending with forward slash ) and add that forward slash to the beginning of your endpoint in AddProductApi.

Comment: not working with this solution

Comment: What's the final url suppose to look like?